# Detectar ausência de luz na camera do Android

Tags: android, android-camera

Preciso capturar a imagem da camera do Android e detectar se o usuário coloca o dedo em cima (escuro). Existe alguma biblioteca que faz isso de forma simples?

Obrigado,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca ouvi falar de uma biblioteca assim, acredito que apenas realizando uma checagem direta na imagem capturada para saber. E realizar essa checagem "manualmente" não é tão difícil se não depender de muita precisão.

Por exemplo daria para fazer algo assim:

```
    public static boolean ImagemEscura(Bitmap img)
    {
        float totalpixel = img.getWidth() * img.getHeight();
        float totalpixelescuro = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
            {
                int cor = img.getPixel(x, y);
                //supondo que o valor como sendo escuro significa que a soma dos
                //valores RGB não podem ultrapassar 90
                if(SomaRGB(cor) > 90)
                {
                    totalpixelescuro++;
                }
            }
        }       
        //se existir mais de 75% dos pixels escuro ele entende que o dedo esta na frente
        return totalpixelescuro/totalpixel > 0.75f;
    }

    public static int SomaRGB(int cor)
    {
        return getRed(cor) + getGreen(cor) + getBlue(cor);
    }

    public static int getRed(int argb) 
    {
        return argb >> 16 & 0xFF;
    }

    public static int getGreen(int argb)
    {
        return argb >> 8 & 0xFF;
    }

    public static int getBlue(int argb)
    {
        return argb & 0xFF;
    }
```

Talvez seja necessário colocar ela para rodar em uma Thread fora da UI para evitar algum crash na App e realizar alguns ajustes nos parâmetros para atender com mais precisão suas necessidades, mas imagino que isso já seja um norte para você.